# Adding class by using classlist.add javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add a new class upon some event.

The new class has different image which I expect to impose over the previously existing class.

So what I observe in DOM, I can see both of these classes (existing one and newly added). I expect the latest added to take effect but DOM shows the added class as deleted and existing one as applied.

Did anyone face this issue sometime and give me an idea what could be going wrong. At another place in code, the same things works and DOM shows the existing class as deleted and the new one as applied?

Comment: can u put some code which what you are trying to do

Comment: @kk123 maybe you should try removing the previously added class and then adding a new one? it sounds like your previous class is  overridden by the new one. `node.classList.remove(prevClass)` followed by `node.classList.add(newClass)`...